# The hover function for the image tag isn't working. How can I fix this?

Tags: html, css, image, hover

```css
h1{
    color:red;
    font-size: 100px;
}


img :hover {
    background-color: gold;
}


.bacon{
    background-color: green;
}

.broccoli{
    background-color: red;
}

/*
.circular{
    border-radius: 100%;
}
*/


#heading{
background-color: aquamarine;
} 
/*ignore this. i typed this as stack overflow was giving me this error 'It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.'.but there is nothing much to explain about this code.*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Bacon Fansite</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1 id="heading">Love Bacon</h1>
  <p>bacon, bacon, bacon, bacon, bacon, bacon</p>
  <p>bacon, bacon, bacon, bacon, bacon, bacon</p>
  <p>bacon, bacon, bacon, bacon, bacon, bacon</p>
  <img class="bacon" src="https://emojipedia-us.s3.amazonaws.com/thumbs/240/apple/118/bacon_1f953.png" alt="bacon-img">
  <img class="broccoli circular" src="https://emojipedia-us.s3.dualstack.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/thumbs/120/apple/325/broccoli_1f966.png" alt="broccoli-img">
</body>

</html>
```

The hover function for the image tag isn't working.
according to the code the background-color of the image has to change to gold on mouse hover but it doesn't happen.

Answer (score 3):

Just remove the space between `img` and `:hover`

```css
h1{
    color:red;
    font-size: 100px;
}


img:hover {
    background-color: gold;
}


.bacon{
    background-color: green;
}

.broccoli{
    background-color: red;
}

/*
.circular{
    border-radius: 100%;
}
*/


#heading{
background-color: aquamarine;
} 
/*ignore this. i typed this as stack overflow was giving me this error 'It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.'.but there is nothing much to explain about this code.*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Bacon Fansite</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1 id="heading">Love Bacon</h1>
  <p>bacon, bacon, bacon, bacon, bacon, bacon</p>
  <p>bacon, bacon, bacon, bacon, bacon, bacon</p>
  <p>bacon, bacon, bacon, bacon, bacon, bacon</p>
  <img class="bacon" src="https://emojipedia-us.s3.amazonaws.com/thumbs/240/apple/118/bacon_1f953.png" alt="bacon-img">
  <img class="broccoli circular" src="https://emojipedia-us.s3.dualstack.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/thumbs/120/apple/325/broccoli_1f966.png" alt="broccoli-img">
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code.

```
h1{
    color:red;
    font-size: 100px;
}


img:hover {
    background-color: gold;
}


.bacon{
    background-color: green;
}

.broccoli{
    background-color: red;
}

/*
.circular{
    border-radius: 100%;
}
*/


#heading{
background-color: aquamarine;
}
```